# Cannot position custom view loaded from nib

Tags: ios, uiview, nib

I want to show some information annotated on a map and below the map I want to show a very simple **custom date picker.**

I created a custom view **in a nib** and associated it with an instance of UIView.

This same class contains this function to load the view instance from a nib.

```
+(id)loadCustomDatePicker
{
    CustomDatePicker *customDatePicker = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomDatePicker" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

    if ([customDatePicker isKindOfClass:[CustomDatePicker class]])
        return customDatePicker;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Here is my screenshot from interface builder.

[image]

In my view controller's **viewDidAppear** method, I am using this code to load the custom view

```
CustomDatePicker *customDatePicker = [CustomDatePicker loadCustomDatePicker];

[self.view addSubview:customDatePicker];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:customDatePicker];

customDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 375, 320, 40);
```

Here is the simulation screenshot:

[image]

Dimensions of the custom view have been set to 320 x 40 in the nib file. Background is transparent.

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM:**

Since height of the scene is 504, my code should have been

```
 customDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 464, 320, 40);
```

But when I implement this I can only see the map. Even (0,400), (0,420) does not work. I used trial and error and used (0,375).

**Visually my objective seems to be complete. But I dont know why (0,375) is working when it is not supposed to work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which view 'self.view' is. It looks like that view is the map only (not including the search bar). Why don't you set

```
customDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.size.height - 40, 320, 40)
```

then you are not dependent on the actual size of the view (which will differ between iPhone 4 and 5 anyways).

BTW, `viewDidAppear` is a strange method to add the bar, `viewDidLoad` is intended for that. Add it in `viewDidLoad`, then set its frame in `viewViewAppear`.

Comment: Thanks, CGRectMake(0, self.view.size.height - 40, 320, 40) works! However if I put the datepicker initialization code in viewDidLoad it does not work. I dont know why.

Comment: Sorry, yes, in viewDidLoad the view frames have not been set correctly yet. I have updated my answer.